How do I webscrape a table from game results on basketball reference using beautiful soup
I'm trying to scrape and parse a table of results from basketball reference using Beautiful soup in python.
Here is the page i'm trying to scrape: https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202310270BOS.html
I want to parse the miami heat basic stats with id "box-MIA-game-basic"
page=requests.get(f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202301270BOS.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
print(soup.find(id='box-MIA-game-basic'))

When i run this the output is "None"
how can I get it to output the parsed table?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Let pandas do the heavy lifting for you. It uses beautifulsoup under the hood.
Code:
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202310270BOS.html'
df = pd.read_html(url, attrs={ 'id': 'box-MIA-game-basic'}, header=1)[0]

Output:
print(df.to_string())
            Starters             MP             FG            FGA            FG%             3P            3PA            3P%             FT            FTA            FT%            ORB            DRB            TRB            AST            STL            BLK            TOV             PF            PTS            +/-
0        Tyler Herro          40:18             10             20           .500              5             12           .417              3              3          1.000              1              5              6              6              1              0              3              2             28             -1
1        Bam Adebayo          35:01             10             23           .435              0              0            NaN              7              9           .778              3              4              7              2              1              2              3              1             27              0
2       Jimmy Butler          33:41              3             11           .273              0              0            NaN              8              9           .889              2              3              5              3              1              1              1              1             14              0
3         Kyle Lowry          31:49              5              7           .714              3              4           .750              0              0            NaN              1              7              8              5              0              1              1              3             13             -1
4         Kevin Love          20:32              3              7           .429              2              4           .500              1              2           .500              2              7              9              2              1              0              0              1              9            +13
5           Reserves             MP             FG            FGA            FG%             3P            3PA            3P%             FT            FTA            FT%            ORB            DRB            TRB            AST            STL            BLK            TOV             PF            PTS            +/-
6    Duncan Robinson          24:19              3              7           .429              3              6           .500              0              0            NaN              0              1              1              0              0              0              0              2              9            -12
7          Dru Smith          23:07              3              6           .500              3              4           .750              0              0            NaN              1              1              2              3              3              1              1              2              9            -18
8   Jaime Jaquez Jr.          14:19              0              2           .000              0              1           .000              0              0            NaN              0              2              2              2              0              0              1              2              0             -8
9      Thomas Bryant          12:59              1              5           .200              0              1           .000              0              0            NaN              1              3              4              1              0              1              1              1              2             -8
10        Jamal Cain           3:55              0              1           .000              0              1           .000              0              0            NaN              0              1              1              0              1              0              1              1              0             -5
11      R.J. Hampton   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play
12      Nikola Jović   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play
13      Caleb Martin  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress  Did Not Dress
14  Orlando Robinson   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play   Did Not Play
15       Team Totals            240             38             89           .427             16             33           .485             19             23           .826             11             34             45             24              8              6             12             16            111            NaN

